# jquery accordion with single links

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a xml document that i'm using XSLT to create an accordion.  The xslt/xml should only create an accordion of an h3 if the folder has a child. At the same time, I need the accordion to generate single page links. How can I accomplish this?  The ordering does matter so I can't move the single page links outside of the accordion div....

My Single page link to Google breaks the accordion. I'd like to keep all of the elements h3s. Is there a way to get the accordion to ignore h3s that don't have a div sibling?

http://jsfiddle.net/gcqmv/

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
            <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
            <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <h3><a href="google.html">Single Page Link to Google</a></h3>

    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Is it because you aren't closing your /a?

Answer (score 0):

Your ul tag after the google link does not have an opening "<". The a is missing the closing tag too, making everything that follows a live link to google. I also threw it in an html structure like so and seems to work for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
            <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <h3><a href="google.html">Single Page Link to Google</a></h3>

    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

for future stackoverflowers, I just targeted the accordion code with a header class.

```
    <script>
    $(function() {

        $("h3").siblings(".banner").not(".active").hide();



        $( "#accordion" ).accordion( { header: 'h3.folder', collapsible: true});
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
    <h3 class="folder">Section 1</h3>
    <div>
            <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <h3 class="folder">Section 2</h3>
    <div>
            <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <h3><a href="google.html">Single Page Link to Google</a></h3>

    <h3 class="folder">Section 3</h3>
    <div>
        ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```